# Get the default name of the streamed pdf upon clicking on "Save As"

Tags: java, jsp

I have a problem that I didn't know exactly how to address, I hope that this will explain it as good as you would need to understand:

I have a streamed pdf file that is previewed on Internet Explorer 11, when I click on "Save as", the default name for the file to be downloaded is the page name where this pdf is streamed, my concern is how I can find a way to set this page's name on response so this pdf plugin would grap and put it in the dialogue box

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your HttpResponse, you need to set the `Content-Disposition` header like this:

```
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="myfile.txt"
```

In addition to have the default PDF viewer recognized the file type, you need to set the `Content-Type` response header to: application/pdf like:

```
Content-Type: application/pdf
```

Here is an example servlet that does this correctly:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class FileServlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet implements javax.servlet.Servlet {
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    process(request, response);
  }

  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
      IOException {
    process(request, response);
  }

  private void process(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
      IOException {

    String pdfFileName = "pdftest.pdf";
    String contextPath = getServletContext().getRealPath(File.separator);
    File pdfFile = new File(contextPath + pdfFileName);

    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + pdfFileName);
    response.setContentLength((int) pdfFile.length());

    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(pdfFile);
    OutputStream responseOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
    int bytes;
    while ((bytes = fileInputStream.read()) != -1) {
      responseOutputStream.write(bytes);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `downloaded is the page name where this pdf is streamed,` I hope OP knows how to add a file name using `Content-Disposition` as a static file name, but here the catch is setting the jsp file name from where the request for pdf is raised.

Comment: If the OP is using a JSP to process the PDF, this still appies. A JSP is itself a servlet anyway and has the provided implicit variable `response` available to the JSP. So, the OP can simply use the methods shown in the servlet on `response` to set the content type and disposition.